# Event 4625 windows security auditing failed to logon. Failure Reason:Unknown user name or bad password

Tags: windows, security, azure, events, logging

I have Windows server 2012 R2 azure virtual instance and few ports are open on it i.e. (80,443,RDC). I have observed the below logs into windows event viewer in security section.

Event 4625 : Microsoft windows security auditing

-------log description start
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       ALLISON
    Account Domain:

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason: Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.

-------log description end

The logs are continuously generating in event viewer (3-4 request per second) and account name always changes as mention below.

1. Account For Which Logon Failed:
   Security ID:        NULL SID
   Account Name:       ATCNSBAYFG
2. Account For Which Logon Failed:
   Security ID:        NULL SID
   Account Name:       SUPPORT
3. Account For Which Logon Failed:
   Security ID:        NULL SID
   Account Name:       SUPPORT
4. Account For Which Logon Failed:
   Security ID:        NULL SID
   Account Name:       HAYLEY
5. Account For Which Logon Failed:
   Security ID:        NULL SID
   Account Name:       TEST5
   and more...

What I tried:
1. Disabled the all open ports from azure portal even RDC.
2. Disabled the Windows Essentials services.
3. Disabled Alert Evaluations task from windows scheduler.

but still the logs are generating in event viewer. Is this windows attacked or some thing else? and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

For testing, remove EVERYONE from folder and use local group Users with modify permission instead of EVERYONE.

4625: An account failed to log on 
https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4625

Some application usually use the guest account to achieve some function, if you worry about the safety you can keep the disable or enable base on your practical application.

Can you turn on failure auditing for authentication attempts?

Get help fro this auditing [solution](https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/active-directory-auditing.html) to track the source of failed logon attempts in Active Directory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answer to this and came across this post. In the end I raised a paid Microsoft support case which came up with the following solution and wanted to share in case it helps anyone in the future:

1. Export the .cer file used for the WCF connection (unless it available elsewhere already):
   a.   Launch the manage local computer certificates mmc plugin
   b.   Navigate to **Trusted People** > **Certificates**
   c.   Right click on the coreapi.server01.gold.nas.faa.gov cert and click **All tasks** > **Export**.
   d.   Click **Next**
   e.   Click **Next** (DER encoded binary X.509 (.CER) is fine).
   f.   Choose a sensible place to export (i.e. Documents)
   g.   Click **Next**
   h.   Click **Finish**
   i.  Click **OK** on dialog that pops up.
2. Open **Windows administrative tools** from the start menu
3. Double click on **Active Directory Users and Computers**
4. In the menu click on **View** > **Advanced Features**
5. Double click on **Users**
6. Right click on suitable account (You can use any account I think but I used our special services account. The Microsoft support engineer also implied you can use a computer too)
7. Click on **Name Mappings…**
8. Click **Add**
9. Select exported cert from step **1**.
10. Click **Open**
11. Click **OK** (leave both identity Mapping options ticked)
12. Click **OK**.

No need to reboot. The login failure is replaced with a login success (4648) which shouldn't trigger an intrusion detection issues.